# Preventing multiple buttons from being touched at the same time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, ios, multi-touch

In iOS is there anyway to prevent a UIView containing multiple buttons (siblings) from being simultaneously from being touched? For instance, two non-overlapping buttons that are side by side can be tapped at the same time with two touches.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Set UIView.exclusiveTouch.

Comment: Awesome! Why I didn't think of that for buttons I do not know?!

Comment: Perfect ! that was like hidden treasure , never knew of this property, thanks a lot.

Comment: please note to set it on each "UIButton"! NOT the the UIView those buttons are in :) (Set in on all subviews of that UIView would do)

like this -> [self.controlView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setExclusiveTouch:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

Comment: @Hlung: That won't necessarily work; `-setExclusiveTouch:` takes a BOOL, not a NSNumber (it might work if the number happens to be interpreted as YES, but that's not guaranteed). I call it `UIView.exclusiveTouch` because that's the class that the property is defined in (a UIButton is a UIView).

Comment: @tc. Yes, it is guaranteed. As far as I know, when I want to send a BOOL in `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:`, sending any object with non-zero address will be interpreted as **YES** (yeah,  `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]` will mean **YES**). And therefore, sending `nil` will be **NO**. In my example, I just want to make it clear that it is a YES. At least it's my style because I don't know a more proper way of doing it :)

Comment: @Hlung: It is *definitely not* guaranteed by the docs, which say "The method must take a single argument of type id". AIUI on x86, if the address is divisible by 256 then it will be equivalent to NO (since BOOL is a signed char so it only looks at the bottom 8 bits). I've also heard of UIKit interpreting 2 as NO (i.e. the code only looks at the bottom bit; unsurprising).

Answer (score 12):

You can also use below method. If you have two buttons or more, to prevent multiple push at a time.

for e.g,

```
[Button1 setExclusiveTouch:YES];

[Button2 setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

Set this method in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4 Syntax:

```
    buttonA.isExclusiveTouch = true
    buttonB.isExclusiveTouch = true
```

Comment: That answer does not really provide an addition to the already existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(UIView* v in self.view.subviews)
    {
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton* btn = (UIButton*)v;
        [yourButton setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find all buttons on that view and set the "**exclusiveTouch**" property to **true** in order to prevent multi touch at the same time.

```
func exclusiveTouchForButtons(view: UIView) {
    for cmp in view.subviews {
        if let cmpButton = cmp as? UIButton {
            cmpButton.exclusiveTouch = true
        } else {
            exclusiveTouchForButtons(cmp)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have tried both  multiTouchEnabled and exclusiveTouch but unfortunately 
none of them workout for me.I have tried the following code worked 
perfectly.
```

### Set this code at .h file

```
BOOL ClickedBool;
```

### Set the following code at method start.

```
if(ClickedBool==TRUE)
{
     return;
}
else
{
    ClickedBool=TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable the exclusive touch you need to set the property `isExclusiveTouch` for each element.

```
myView.isExclusiveTouch = true
```

If you would want that the default behaviour changes you could use the UIAppearance of the UIView class.

```
UIView.appearance().isExclusiveTouch = true
```